# process.env calls cause 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: node.js, express, dotenv

I've isolated the problem down to the code using process.env.[something]. I am hosting my web app on a ubuntu droplet with nginx. This web app worked fine when accessing from a localhost, but when trying to run the app from the server, a 502 Bad Gateway is thrown. If I comment out all the code using data from the .env file, then the app works (without the functions I comment out, of course).

Any help would be fantastic.

The .env file is in the same directory as my main app file (server.js).

Relevant code from server.js file

```
require('dotenv').config();

const express = require('express');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoDBStore = require('connect-mongodb-session')(session);
// const { ExpressOIDC } = require('@okta/oidc-middleware');

const app = express();
const searchRouter = require('./routes/search');
const oidc = new ExpressOIDC({
  issuer: `${process.env.ORG_URL}/oauth2/default`,
  client_id: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
  client_secret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
  redirect_uri: `${process.env.HOST_URL}/authorization-code/callback`,
  scope: 'openid profile',
  appBaseUrl: process.env.HOST_URL
});
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using right ports? Nginx and node app use different ports to host their services

Comment: @AdrianSolarczyk I have set the port for Nginx in /etc/nginx/sites-available/default to be 3010, which is the same as the port set in the express file. I am able to load all pages fine, as long as they don't reference any data from the .env file.

Comment: Are you using localhost or domain in nginx configuration? Did you log out the `process.env.YOUR_VARIABLES` to ensure they are what you want them to be?

Comment: @AdrianSolarczyk I am using a domain in the Nginx configuration. The variables are correct. I've been reading that using the npm package dotenv is not recommended for this sensitive data in production. How should I store/access this information in a production setting?

Comment: For sensitive data you should use RSA algorithm which is provided by Nodejs built-in library `crypto`. The problem is nginx web server and node app *shouldn't work* on the same ports. You should use nginx proxy pass to your locally hosted Node.js app.